# Can an AngularJS directive template render another directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive such that the template contains another directive:

```
var myModule = angular.module('mymodule', []);

myModule.directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
          config: '@'
       },
       template: '<div ng-controller="mycontroller", ng-init={{config}}><directive2 config={{config}}></directive2></div>'
    }
}
```

The code is a little bit strange tho, and the purpose of directive1 is to act like a "wrapper", such that it takes the config and then pass it along to "mycontroller" and directive2.

I tried that but somehow the mycontroller doesn't take the config; It said that config is undefined.

Just wonder does it support in Angular or is there a better way for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add quotes around your attributes. Also, don't need commas between html attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use nested directives.

But you have few mistakes in your directive template. Look at the example below and fix your template accordingly.

```
.directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
          config: '='
       },
       template: '<div>Config1:{{config}}<directive2 config="config"></directive2></div>',
       link: function(scope) {
         scope.config = {
           test: 'from directive1'
         };
       }
    }
})

.directive('directive2', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
          config: '='
       },
       template: '<div>config2: {{config}}</div>'
    }
});
```

Finally, here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMUKW8L6HlraUinSKaRz?p=preview) that show nested directives.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are creating a new controller using `ng-controller="mycontroller"` in your directive template.

ng-controller creates a new scope, so the config object does not exist in the scope of mycontroller. If you simply remove `ng-controller="mycontroller"`, it will work.